# How to add multiple audio play buttons that stop each other?

Tags: html, audio

I have an HTML list of music tracks in a website. Some of them can be previewed with an audio sample.

I want to implement a triangle (play button) in front of each of those tracks, so that the visitor can click on each of those and hear a short audio sample. If the visitor clicks on another track before the previous is done, the latter should stop and the new one should play.

Is this simple plan implementable without much effort? I am good at HTML and CSS, but i can't write JavaScript.  I've researched the audio-controls attribute, but it gives me a complete player with a bunch of controls that i don't want displayed.

Are there any tutorials you guys could point me to, if this is only possible with java-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, no answer for weeks...

But i found a solution myself. Everything that i described works with a small jQuery player i found here: https://github.com/kuantal/Multiple-circular-player . I can have multiple instances and the script is "intelligent" enough to let only one single instance play at the same time.

Props to the author of the script - well done!